# How to open a project with IntelliJ without Gradle?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to open a project with IntelliJ, the only problem is that when I open it with the IDE I am asked to use Gradle to import it. I do not want Gradle to look for dependencies and such because I do not have access to them. There seem to be no options for me to bypass this issue, and in the end IntelliJ refuse to import the project because it cannot download some of the dependencies.

At the moment I'm using a hack: I open the parent folder instead of the right folder. But this mean I cannot take advantage of the IDE's feature like finding the implementation or usage of a function.

Any idea what I could do?

Comment: Could it be that the project your are trying to open is a *gradle* based project?

Comment: Edit gradle build file commenting all the dependencies, create project and restore the gradle build file. Ignore autoimport dependency option in IDEA

Comment: @GhostCat: it is a gradle based project.

Comment: @StanislavL: could I just delete all the .gradle files?

Comment: So, you have an X project, and you want to open it, ignoring its X nature - and why again do you expect that to work?

Comment: Because in the end these are just files?

Comment: No. It's better to leave them. Idea creates all the structures/paths according to gradle dirs structure and the files could be useful

Comment: unfortunately I can't open the project if I leave them, because the dependencies are incomplete (I can't be completed)

Comment: I had the same issue - another hack I did (that worked for me) was disabling the gradle plugin (doing so disable another 2 dependent plugin) - then I could open the project regularly. Surprisingly, after re-enable the gradle plugin its still works...

Comment: Same problem here.  I don't want the project to work, I just want to look at the files.  Thanks to dWinder, your solution works for me.